# Understanding ElGamal encryption for a Mental Poker Case

Tags: elgamal-encryption, mental-poker, hashed-elgamal

I am looking to understand ElGamal encryption as it is used in a specic context described below. I am interested in creating a practical form of Mental Poker for games other than poker developed by Phillip Golle in 2005 found here: http://crypto.stanford.edu/~pgolle/papers/poker.pdf

The paper describes an algo that is modifiable for such other random outcomes (such as non-poker games). Another professor in the field (Green) pointed out some minor issues with Golle's work which included how card collisions are handed in the single deck Poker version (https://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2012/04/02/poker-is-hard-especially-for/).

I would like to understand a) how to adapt this to other random outcomes b) how a consensus protocol might work to deal with players timing out, leaving or entering in the middle of a game or shuffle (not described by Golle) which includes how the leaving parties keys are managed by the remaining players from the timed-out or leaving players; c) and, understand how you modify the process to remove the issues that are described by Green when card collisions happen in single deck poker or another single deck games.

Further comments:

1. Its  essentially an infinite deck solution since cards are calculated on the fly,  but what if you wanted to say limit the model simulate a 6 deck game of say baccarat?

   2. I'm guessing the solution is simple. Since this version of mental poker doesn't shuffle any deck but creates cards for deck on the fly: if a player leave, times out or refuses to show his hand he loses the pot and.no one can see their hands - so no damage done. It can be based on some predetermined time limits and adjusted to GMT and even if he/she leaves before providing the key for all other players then new cards are dealt ( I think) to remaining players (sicne no one saw the old ones anyway) or if shown then it doesn't matter
   3. No comments on this tricky point.

Comment: I cant seem to get any answer anyway!  Not generating much interest...strange as this is an interesting area in Cryptography I would have thought...